# Grails create-app error

Tags: macos, grails, groovy, terminal

Anyone know why I would get this error when trying to create a grails app using terminal.

```
mycomputer:test-apps mailboxe$ grails create-app demo
| Configuring classpath
| Error Error executing script CreateApp: /Users/bla/.grails/ivy-cache/resolved-org.grails.internal-grails-2.0.3.xml (Permission denied) (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Phillip Tenn mentions, this is a permissions issue.  Chances are something got installed into a cache with the `sudo` command so the root user owns the file and your normal user can't modify it.

The easiest thing to do is probably to just whack your `~/.grails` directory, by default, there isn't anything but cached information in there.  So unless you've put something in there manually (like a config file), it's safe to delete and let it regenerate with the next `grails` command.  To do that, just:

```
cd ~
sudo rm -r .grails
```

It'll prompt you for your password to ensure you want to run this command as the root user.

Alternatively, you could try to find the offending file and `chown` it to your user and group (by default on OSX the group is `staff`).  So for this example:

```
sudo chown bla:staff /Users/bla/.grails/ivy-cache/resolved-org.grails.internal-grails-2.0.3.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Grails needs to be able to write to a .grails folder under your user directory.

Without knowing the details of your development environment, the error message you are getting says `(Permission denied)` when you try to run `grails create-app demo`.

I would look into your directories:

```
/Users/bla/.grails/
/Users/bla/.grails/ivy-cache/
```

and ensure that you have proper write permissions.

Comment: Thanks Philip how would I ensure I have the appropriate write permissions?

Comment: That would be OS-dependent.  Are you running *NIX or Windows?

Comment: Oh. Unfortunately I don't know much about Mac OS X (I live in the Linux/Unix and Windows world). Consequently, I don't know much about how User permissions work in that environment.  I would think that you could use standard chmod command, but I could not say for certain.

Comment: Mac OS X is a Unix system. You can open Terminal and inspect the permissions on your `~/.grails` directory.